# Automatically publishing new added product to social media

Tags: automation, social

I want to add this functionality to my store, when the store owner add a new product to the store. I want to share this product automatically in social media hubs (Facebook, Instagram, twitter and google+), share it on Facebook like posting it on a facebook page.

I don't know where I should start. Could you give me a hint how to do this?

**Edit one:** I think it is better to handle the process of auto posting using script files. Suppose I have a controller outside Magento scope that will use Magento SOAP api to get the product then post it to social network. I want a way to pass the product id to this controller when the admin adds the product using get request. I searched inside the code and found two ways to do it.

First way to override `saveAction()` in `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController`. And the second way to override `_afterSave()`in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` which one is better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveAction()`: won't catch products added outside of an actual admin creating the product.

`_afterSave()`: called *any* time the product is saved. Just be wary of that.

The above information are foundational to deciding which is better for you (and your client's) purposes.

Comment: could you please explain more about saveAction(). I didn't get the meaning of "added outside of an actual admin creating the product"

Comment: "outside of an actual admin creating a product"... Creation via import/API/third party script. May not apply. Clear?

Answer (score 0):

Though this is self-promotion, I thought to share this to anyone who is looking for such kind of extension on their Magento store despite spending lot of hours developing it.

We have already developed an extension which specifically does this. Our bulk social networks auto poster sends products information like Name, SKU, Price, Image, etc to various social networking sites - Facebook, Pinterest, Twitter. You can check out all the features and buy link on the Magento connect. It also works on Magento 2! https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-pinterest.html